# C++ template member function already defined with same type

Tags: c++, templates, type-parameter

I have this simple code below, a template with 2 type parameters. If I declare my class with the same type (like `BidirectionalMap<int,int>`), I receive an error:

```
int BidirectionalMap<T,S>::operator [](T) const' : member function already defined or declared
```

Here's my template code:

```
template <class T, class S>

class BidirectionalMap{
    int count(T t){
        return 1;
    }
    int count(S s){
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you want if `T` and `S` are same type ? (currently `count` has same implementation, but is it just for example ?)

Comment: yeah, it's just an example not to confuse you guys, the implementation of count doesn't matter, I just need to use count on a map's value, and it's key as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you got is normal, because after substitution you have

```
template <>
class BidirectionalMap<int, int>
{
    int count(int t){ return 1; }
    int count(int s){ return 1; } // Duplicated method
};
```

To solve that, you may provide partial specialization:

```
template <class T>
class BidirectionalMap<T, T>
{
    int count(T t) { return 1; }
};
```

In C++20, you might use `requires` to "discard" methods:

```
template <class T, class S>
class BidirectionalMap
{
    int count(T t) requires(!std::is_same<T, S>::value) { /*..*/ }
    int count(S s) requires(!std::is_same<T, S>::value) { /*..*/ }
    int count(T t) requires( std::is_same<T, S>::value) { /*..*/ }
};
```